# Complemented subspace of Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $M$ and $N$ be closed subspaces of a Banach space $X$, and every $x$ in $X$ can be expressed in the form $m+n$ for $m\in M$ and $n\in N$ in exactly one way, show that there exists $C>0$ such that $\|m\|_X,\|n\|_X\leq C\|x\|_X$ for all $x$.

The hint tell me to use the open mapping theorem, but I don't know how to construct a surjective map? The projection map $\pi_M:M+N\to M$, $m+n\mapsto m$ is not what I want.

Comment: Why don't you want to work with the projection map?

Comment: @UmbertoP. If I use the projection map, I need to show the continuity. It seems to be even harder.

Comment: Perhaps you want the map from $M\oplus N$ to $X$

Comment: $\alpha \colon M \times N \to X,\; (m,n) \mapsto m+n$

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for you hint, I think I have got the answer. It's clear $\alpha$ is continuous linear map from $M\oplus N$ to $X$. Moreover, $\alpha$ is surjective. By open mapping theorem, for every $x=m+n$, there is $u\in M\oplus N$ such that $\alpha(u)=x$ and $\|u\|_{M\oplus N}\leq C\|x\|_X$. From the assumption, we have $u=(m,n)$, therefore $\|(m,n)\|_{M\oplus N}=\max(\|m\|_X,\|n\|_X)\leq C\|x\|_X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved in the comments:

> Consider $\alpha \colon M \times N \to X,\; (m,n) \mapsto m+n$ -- [Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525870/complemented-subspace-of-banach-space#comment3107253_1525870)

> It's clear $\alpha$ is continuous linear map from $M\oplus N$ to $X$. Moreover, $\alpha$ is surjective. By open mapping theorem, for every $x=m+n$, there is $u\in M\oplus N$ such that $\alpha(u)=x$ and $\|u\|_{M\oplus N}\leq C\|x\|_X$. From the assumption, we have $u=(m,n)$, therefore $\|(m,n)\|_{M\oplus N}=\max(\|m\|_X,\|n\|_X)\leq C\|x\|_X$. -- [Xiang Yu](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525870/complemented-subspace-of-banach-space#comment3107309_1525870)